# Stepped forms using angularjs 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a form with steps using angular-ui bootstap tabs as containers.  However I cannot get ng-submit to call a function in the page's controller.

Does ng-submit call before or after validation is successful? Could the other subforms be conflicting with this?

The content of each form is held in partial html files and brought in by ng-include inside an ng-repeat.

Here's roughly how the main template looks (it, and its controller is brought in by ng-route/ng-view

```
<form name="outerForm">
  <tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="(key, step) in steps" disabled="step.disabled">
       <form name="innerForm" ng-submit="nextStep(key)">
          <ng-include src="step.template"></ng-include>
          <input type="submit" value="Next Step" />
       </form>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
</form>
```

The included `step.template` file only contains an input at the moment:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="data.title" name="title" required />
```

The JS function is just a console log:

```
//from inside the view's controller
$scope.nextStep = function(key){
    console.log(key);
};

 //steps array for reference, also inside the controller
 $scope.steps = [
    {id: 'details', title: 'Details', disabled: false, template:'_form-details.html'},
    {id: 'contact', title: 'Contact', disabled: false, template:'_form-contact.html'},
    ///.... (there are 4 steps, a 5th maybe be added dynamically
 ];
```

I want to use this function to enable the next tab/step and take the user there, if they have passed the validation for this step.  Does anyone know why this won't submit?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like your ng-submit function expects a 'key' object, but your ng-model is a 'data' object. I'd try making it the same object, either key.title or nextStep(data).

Comment: Does the ngSubmit have to match the ng-model? My plan is for the steps to include multiple inputs (some quite complicated) and for it to continue if all pass validation.  The nextStep function is to work out if and where to step